# Why the numbers are wrong, when I use range(1, 101) in Geany?

Tags: python, range, geany

When I use `range(1, 101)` in Geany, something strange happens. What's wrong?

This is my code:

```
for number in range(1, 101):
    print(number)
```

This is what I got in Geany:

```
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
8
8
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
10
```

I've tried the same code in terminal, it worked well. But in Geany, it didn't work. HELP!

Comment: Reset Geany's settings to their defaults and disable all plugins and see if the problem persists.

Comment: What happens if you change the endpoints of the range function? Does it provide the same wrong numbers?

Comment: I‘ve tried another endpoint, it still wrong.

Comment: Check what is configured in "Build->Set Build Commands" menu, there are the commands defined to use when building and executing your code.
For me, the code above gives the expected results when executed in Geany, so it is likely to be related to your configuration.